# Submit Button to Open Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons.  One button is to submit a certain task to be executed but for simplicity of this question I chose to, echo a text to a screen and the other button is to open the module.  Both works fine.  Is it possible to have my submit do both, so it will perform a certain task, in this example, echo to a screen and also open a module??

I don't know how to go about doing this.

Here's my code

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    echo "Echo from Submit Button"  
   }
}
?>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type='submit' name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"> Submit </button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should be able to do that using Javascript. I believe I have done something similar in the past, but I don't have any code handy. I believe though, using Javascript, you can toggle the modal, once you get the element. That should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: This is what I have, but it doesn't work. It just executes the PHP on submit but it won't open the modal.  I would like the button to execute the PHP script on "submit" and open the modal as well.  Any ideas on how I can go about doing this??

Comment: Here's my code:  
    <div class="col" id="displayModal"><button type='submit' name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Submit </button></div>

    <script>
        $('#displayModal').on('submit', function(e){
            $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>

Comment: Don't have the button be a submit button. Then add an onclick event to call the JavaScript function that will show the modal, and then call the PHP.

Comment: Or something else you could do. Add a variable to your php code, something like, `$loadModal = false`. In the HTML code, have a hidden span or other element and echo the value out into the element. In Javascript, you could then have an `onLoad` function that will check for the value of that element. If it's set to true, show the modal, if false, do nothing. You can change the PHP variable after the form is submitted, where you're checking `isset`.